# What determines the size of the types transform feedback writes to its buffer?

Tags: glsl, webgl, webgl2

(This question is in the context of WebGL, but to my knowledge applies to all GLSL.) My understanding is that GLSL primitives can have varying precision (number of bits, and therefore bytes), depending on the environment they're running in. How does this impact what gets written out to a transform feedback buffer?

Pretending I have a vertex buffer that writes out a `float` value, should I expect what is written to the output buffer to vary in the same way that precision can? If so, how can I anticipate this in advance and design my program in a way that allows me to correctly interpret what is written?

Answer (score 1):

Discovered the answer right after posting. From the [OpenGL documentation on Transform Feedback](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Transform_Feedback#Captured_data_format):

> #### Captured data format
>
> ...the data is written in the order specified by the varyings​ array
> (when doing interleaved rendering)... Each component of the basic type
> of the output is written in order.
>
> **A component will always be a float/double, signed integer, or unsigned integer, using the sizes for [GLfloat/GLdouble, GLint, and GLuint.](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Type)**